# Python exit early when piping to head

Tags: python, pipe, signals

I have a python script which writes to stdout which I'm piping to `head`

I'm trying to stop the python program when it has produced enough output to satisfy `head` but it's not working when I do small tests.

I've seen mention of `import signal` but I must be using it wrong?

Here's the small test I'm running on linux and mac

`python woo.py | head -n 1`

Where woo.py is:

```
import signal
import time
import sys 

signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE, signal.SIG_DFL)

sys.stdout.write('hello\n')
sys.stdout.write('to\n')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(10)
sys.stdout.write('the\n')
sys.stdout.write('world\n')
```

The idea is that I shouldn't hit the `time.sleep(10)` section because python should be stopping early, but I'm definitely hitting it, even with the flush command

Comment: `head` probably uses buffered input. So it doesn't exit immediately after the first line is written to the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar is right (thank you), when I write to stdout more then I can avoid the `time.sleep` call

```
import signal
import time
import sys 

signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE, signal.SIG_DFL)

sys.stdout.write('hello\n')
sys.stdout.write('to\n')
for i in range(30000):
    sys.stdout.write('the\n')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(10) #does not get here
sys.stdout.write('world\n')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).